# How can I display a countdown counter in Python Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a traffic light management project. So in the UI implementation part, I want to display a countdown counter on the UI for displaying the remaining 'ON' duration of light. I have read that Tkinter is single-threaded. So I don't know exactly how to achieve this. So please help me to complete it.

Comment: Take a look at `root.after(ms, func)`

Comment: Yes, I have used this. But will it not disturb the execution of other functions that are running continuously?

Comment: What are the functions you are talking about? Tkinter mainloop, maybe? If so, you don't need to worry about that in your case (I mean, if you just want to make a countdown timer). But if you are about to run something time consuming, it's a bad idea, because app would not respond during the function is running. In this case you would need to use multiple threads (where Tkinter is in the main thread)

Comment: PS: Tkinter is not "single-threaded", it is "not thread-safe". That means, that you can use other threads together with the Tkinter app, but Tkinter mainloop must be running only in the main one.

Comment: BTW, I have reread your question, and I'd like to clarify: is this a single app, which just simulates traffic light, or does it get information about traffic light from somewhere else? If it really gets and processes real information, threading will likely be a better solution.

Comment: It is a single app in which I have created two classes, one is used for UI widget settings and function, the second one is used for calculating the time duration for the lights.

Comment: Well, so it doesn't get the information about which light is now turned on from external sources but just calculates it on its own, does it?

Comment: If this is the case, there is no need for multiple threads, and `root.after(ms, func)` will be enough

Comment: BTW, of course, it's unnecessary to use a separate class for calculating the time, just create a separate method in the UI class that updates the colors (let's name it "upd_lights") and is called every second. To do it, you can add `root.after(0, self.upd_lights)` to the `__init__`, and add this to the end of the method: `root.after(1000, self.upd_lights)`

Comment: There are _many_ questions on this site related to creating timers and clocks. Please do a bit of research, try to solve the problem yourself, and then ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for elaboration.@Demian Wolf

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach is to remove the last `root.mainloop()`, and replace it with it's equivalent:

```py
while True:
    root.update()
    root.update_idletasks()
```

This way you can put some bit of code inside the while loop that will run forever. Using some global variables (if you need to) and importing `time`, you can do a counter. Here goes my example:

```py
import time
import tkinter as tk

tk = tk.Tk()

###

def everysecond():
    print("One second has passed.")
    # Put here the code to reduce the tkinter counter by one.
    # For example, modify the label.

###

secs = int(time.time())

while True:
    tk.update()
    tk.update_idletasks()

    if int(time.time()) > secs:
        secs = int(time.time())
        everysecond()
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I am a beginner in python UI. I will follow your suggestions.

Comment: Nice! If this works for you, make sure to mark this answer as the correct one :)